# i got a error ORA-01747 when insert data into table

Tags: oracle, dml, ora-01747

i got trouble when insert data using this query :

```
INSERT ALL 
   INTO obat ('id_obat','nama_obat','tanggal_kadarluarsa','stock','harga') 
   VALUES (1, 'Indomethacin', '2023-09-01', 50, 3000)
   SELECT * FROM dual;
```

this is the table query :

```
CREATE TABLE obat (
    id_obat             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    nama_obat           VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    tanggal_kadarluarsa DATE NOT NULL,
    stock               INTEGER NOT NULL,
    harga               NUMBER(20, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT obat_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_obat )
);
```

is somethin wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes are for string literals; identifiers (e.g. column names) should be in double quotes - but only have to be if they were created as quoted identifiers, and then the case of the name has to match the data dictionary name exactly. Yours are not quoted identifiers in the create statement, so you can just do:

```
INSERT ALL 
   INTO obat (id_obat,nama_obat,tanggal_kadarluarsa,stock,harga) 
   VALUES (1, 'Indomethacin', DATE '2023-09-01', 50, 3000)
   SELECT * FROM dual;
```

If you *really* wanted to quote them then you would need to do (including the table name to demonstrate, as the same rules apply):

```
INSERT ALL 
   INTO "OBAT" ("ID_OBAT","NAMA_OBAT","TANGGAL_KADARLUARSA","STOCK,HARGA") 
   VALUES (1, 'Indomethacin', DATE '2023-09-01', 50, 3000)
   SELECT * FROM dual;
```

but that's just more typing and arguably maybe harder to read, and easier to get wrong.

You can read more about quoted and non-quoted identifiers [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html).

With a single row you don't really need `ALL`, you can also do:

```
INSERT INTO obat (id_obat,nama_obat,tanggal_kadarluarsa,stock,harga) 
VALUES (1, 'Indomethacin', DATE '2023-09-01', 50, 3000)
```

Note that I've added the `DATE` keyword to these statements; `'2023-09-01'` is not a date, it's a string literal, so you're relying on Oracle implicitly converting that to an actual date, based on your current session NLS settings. With `DATE '2023-09-01'` that is now a date literal. Again, there is more [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html).

Comment: Thanks, i got it now.

Comment: One of my columns was named COMMENT, which Oracle did not like, generating this exception.  Quoting the field name resolved the issue.